# Autofit rows then add height

Tags: excel, addition, rows, autofilter

I am looking to improve the aesthetics of an excel report. The data is dynamic and when changes, the row height may not be enough to display all the data (long texts). I would like the data to auto fit the height and then add additional height for some space to make it more readable. The amount of height I am seeking to add for each row can be by a constant amount.

I have successfully used autofit on the rows, but I am struggling to add height after that sub is run.

```
Sub autofit()


Rows("7:508").EntireRow.autofit

End Sub
```

See below for current results and what is my expected result:

[Current Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJAF5.png)

[Expected Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rROi.png)

Comment: After doing the autofit you will need to iterate through the rows and change each height: `Rows(7).Height = Rows(7).Height + 10` change the 10 to the spacing you want.

Comment: @Scott Craner I couldn't get this to work. Could you please customize the solution to include the comprehensive code

Comment: sorry it should be `RowHeight` not `Height`: `Rows(7).RowHeight = Rows(7).RowHeight + 10`

Comment: With that, it correctly works for row 7. How would I be able to apply it to my entire range of 7:508.        I tried the following without success: Rows("7:508").RowHeight = Rows("7:508").RowHeight + 10

Comment: You use a for loop `For i = 7 to 508` and use `i` in place of `7`

Comment: The loop works, but it adjusts the size of all rows. I am working with an autofilter, so I wouldn't need the cells that are hidden to be adjusted. How would I create that exception?